# Imaging to Bigger SSD

Tags: windows, server, dns, imaging

I'm planning to image a laptop using Acronis or maybe Clonezilla from a 256GB 2.5" SSD to an NVMe 512GB.

The laptop is assigned to just one person but they have quite a few pieces of proprietary software and configurations, and they're encountering low disk spice and some crashing with some of their specialized apps.

My question: since it's a domain joined computer, is it still OK to image the old drive to the larger drive or should I un-join it from the domain before imaging and rejoin after restoring the image? And if so, when I re-join, would the account pickup the old profile folder from the restored image and be OK with all of their software configurations, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If the proprietary software needs to check the domain for the right license, I'd recommend that you unjoin the domain and then image the disk. As soon as you re-image the new SSD with the old SSD, rejoin the domain. This should allow the software, config files, etc. to reactivate

Usually, domains save the data and configuration files in servers, so you should be good to go. But if the domain is not server-sided, I'd say you need to make the image and then flash it to the new SSD. Usually in the software, you can specify a configuration file to load. They are all on the disk, so even though this manual method takes longer, it is a great alternative.

But I'd also wait for another person to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I should have mentioned the proprietary software etc. is not involved with the server. Just figured I'd mention it as I need the profile to load exactly as is when restoring the image and wasn't sure how well that works when a computer is domain joined. All my past imaging has been non-domain joined PCs that I can remember.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. If the profiles are stored in the server, they may automatically re-apply to the software, but it's best to copy everything and see if there is a way to import it.